# Communication between viewmodels and frequent updates

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, updates, frequency

I started a new WPF with MVVM application.
The main view is a Grid with 2 columns:

- on the left a treeview with only 2 levels (and 2 viewmodels, one for each level).
- on the right, a detail view displaying data loaded from the selected treeviewitem on the right.

I have 2 questions:

1. How should I communicate the Id from the selected treeviewitem on the right to the view model used in the detail view on the right column ?
2. Once the Id is known in the left part, I will call an API to refresh frequently the detail view, up to every 100-200 ms. Is the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern suitable for this kind of development ?

I made some searchs about question 1, I could use a MVVM framework and/or use the mediator pattern.
I just want to keep my application as light and as simple as possible.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a SelectedNode property to your view model. When the tree item is selected, disable the updates on the current SelectedNode, then set the SelectedNode propery to the selected tree items viewmodel and then start the updates on the new node. The detail side just binds to the SelectedNode property/object of your main view model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a SelectedNode but in the view model from the TreeView (level 2 via HierarchicalDataTemplate). And I need the SelectedNode value from this view model to be accessible to the main view view model (or to a new view model) for the detail view.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a messaging pattern (i.e. pub/sub).

Checkout [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or [MessageBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bizmonger.Patterns).

The idea is to broadcast messages for your view-models to respond to.

It is very similar to raising an event for your view-models to respond to.

Using the pub/sub pattern provides loose-coupling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will have a look to the links provided.